# php XMLReader how to get particular item?

Tags: php

I create code for parse xml.and it is like this

```
<?php
$xmlDocument = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <toys>
                    <toy code="10001">
                        <name>Ben 10 Watch</name>
                        <type>Battery Toys</type>
                    </toy>
                    <toy code="10002">
                        <name>Angry Birds Gun</name>
                        <type>Mechanical Toys</type>
                    </toy>
                </toys>';
    $xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->XML($xmlDocument);
    while( $xml->read() ) {
    if($xml->name == "toy") {
        print "ID:" . $xml->getAttribute("code") . "<br/>";
        print $xml->readInnerXML() . "<br/>";
        $xml->next();
    }
}
?>
```

which works fine with no problem and give the output as expected

```
ID:10001
Ben 10 Watch Battery Toys 
ID:10002
Angry Birds Gun Mechanical Toys
```

now i want only one item to be seen in this or for huge xml file how to get one particular item.
for this i create code like this.

```
<?php
$xmlDocument = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <toys>
                    <toy code="10001">
                        <name>Ben 10 Watch</name>
                        <type>Battery Toys</type>
                    </toy>
                    <toy code="10002">
                        <name>Angry Birds Gun</name>
                        <type>Mechanical Toys</type>
                    </toy>
                </toys>';
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->XML($xmlDocument);
$xml->read(0); 
$xml->name == "toy";
print "ID:" . $xml->getAttribute("code") . "<br/>";
print $xml->readInnerXML() . "<br/>";

?>
```

it does not as expected i want only one item to be printed.
how to do this .
summary of question is that how to get particular one item .

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$xml->read(0);
$xml->name == "toy";
print "ID:" . $xml->getAttribute("code") . "<br/>";
print $xml->readInnerXML() . "<br/>";
```

to:

```
$xml->read();
$xml->read();
if($xml->name == "toy")
{
   print "ID:" . $xml->getAttribute("code") . "<br/>";
   print $xml->readInnerXML() . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: dear sir i want only one output to be shown...this will give the all item

Comment: @PatelVilay it is for your second example. because you only execute $xml->read(0) once there would be one output. There is no while or for loop

Comment: @PatelVilay and by the way XMLReader::read doesn't get argument so just use $xml->read() to read once

Comment: @PatelVilay: try two $xml->read(); consecutively like the updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105804/discussion-between-patel-vilay-and-pooya).